# Unable to compile servlet in jetty

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets, jetty

I have a google app engine connected project (in eclipse juno) and it contains a simple servlet file but for some reason when I run the project ,the corresponding class file is not getting created inside WEB-INF/classes folder, in fact there is no classes folder inside WEB-INF. and hence I am unable to run the servlet.I will appreciate if someone could suggest some solution.

Below is my web.xml file->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value>com.queryname.DeviceInfoEndpoint,com.queryname.MessageEndpoint</param-value>
  </init-param>
   <servlet-name>QueryServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.queryname.QueryTest</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>QueryServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Query/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I get the following exception-->

```
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@684528a3{/,C:\Users\User8\workspace\QueryName-AppEngine\war}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: QueryServiceServlet
```

Regards,
Laura.

Comment: You mean when you "Run as Web Application" in Eclipse nothing happens ?

Comment: When I click on "Run as Web Application" the server starts and then as I have mentioned my servlet class in web.xml (with the path com.) and it is unable to find the class file so it throws an exception(class not found).

Comment: Can you please show us how your web.xml look like.

Comment: Move your <servlet-name> and <servlet-class> into their own <servlet> and see if this solves the problem. currently they are under the <servlet> element of the SystemServiceServlet.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<servlet-name>` and `<servlet-class>` into their own `<servlet>` and see if this solves the problem. currently they are under the `<servlet>` element of the `SystemServiceServlet`.

Comment: I did that now I am getting a new set of errors->



-->WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.queryname.QueryTest

-->com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.queryname.QueryTest

-->WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@33c40638{/,C:\Users\User8\workspace\QueryName-AppEngine\war}
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It says it cannot find the class `com.queryname.QueryTest` .. where does this exception occur? is it inside the servlet code ?